# Exclude wordpress from .htaccess rules

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a testing web where there is a testing directory lets say 'test' which contains wordpress directory lets say 'mywordpress', test and his content - excluding the mywordpress - is handled by its own .htaccess - I need the .htaccess to do nothing with the url that goes mydomain.com/test/mywordpressXX (XX can be "/" or "/anything...."

Ive tried something but this .htaccess still works with test content, but throws Internal 500 error when I am trying to reach WP admin:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

DirectorySlash On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1/ [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mywordpress/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/?]+)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mywordpress/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/?]*)/([^/?]*)$ $1.php?$1=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mywordpress/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/?]*)/([^/?]*)/([^/?]*)$ $1.php?$2=$3
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how is it done correctly ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule ^mywordpress(/|$) - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe it was me, Im not sure now - I was testing for mydomain.com/mywordpress instead of mydomain.com/test/mywordpress :) I really like this one, it has better flags and so on :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh ! Silly me ! I forget about the RewriteBase /test/ you just have to make the exclude rule this way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mywordpress/?$
```

There was an additional slash:

<del>`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mywordpress/?$`</del>